# $this->redirect not working

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have this weird dilemma going on. I don't seem to be able to redirect from my login page. `$this->redirect` is working fine from other methods, but not just from this one. I have tried making a dummy method for it, I have tried removing all the eof file white spaces, even tried emptying the cache. This same code seems to be working okay on localhost but as soon as I copied it to the server it start going bonkers on me. My controller code is

```
if ($this->request->is('post'))
{
    $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->request->data['username'])));
    if($user['User']['passwd'] == AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['password']))
    {           
         $this->redirect('http://www.google.com.au/');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong Password";              
    }
}
```

I am using my customized login as Auth Component, didn't seem to get along with me.

AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' =>array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);
```

View:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" class="">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username<br />
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input" value="" size="20" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password<br />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" value="" size="20" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In" />
    </p>
</form>
```

'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
You can set $this->Auth->loginRedirect
```

or this in the *AppControler.php*

```
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index');
```

Comment: see this part `if($user['User']['passwd']`? is this really `['passwd']` instead of `['Password']`?

Comment: Yes... because i used passwd in the database.. do you think it can cause problem??

Comment: I see. Are you new to CakePHP? It would be ideal if you just follow the default procedure on authentication.

Comment: well...it doesn't work the other way as well thats why i changed the field thinking it might be classing with default naming convention... :-)

Comment: Have you tried to google your question? or consult the CakePHP cookbook?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will work. :-)

```
'Auth' => array(
          'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
```